# Retain drop down list value after form submission

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form where a user rates a poem from 1 to 3.  My code is as follows:

```
<select name="rating">
<cfif len(duplicateCheck.score)><option value="#duplicateCheck.score#">You scored:  #duplicateCheck.score#</option>
<cfelse><option value="">&ndash; Rate This Poem &ndash;</option>
</cfif>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

If the user has already rated the poem, I am trying to make their previous score be selected.  If not, the user can select 1-3.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you're storing the fact that the user has already rated the poem.  But from a high level:

```
<option value="1"<cfif userHasSelected eq 1> selected="selected"</cfif>>1</option>
<option value="2"<cfif userHasSelected eq 2> selected="selected"</cfif>>2</option>
<option value="3"<cfif userHasSelected eq 3> selected="selected"</cfif>>3</option>
```

So, do you already have a handle on whether or not the user has rated the poem?  Or is that the actual question?

Comment: Thanks Charlie.  To determine is the user has rated the poem, I use:

<!--- Validate first name. --->
  <cfif NOT Len( FORM.rating )>
   <cfset ArrayAppend(
    arrErrors,
    "You must rate the poem."
    ) />
  </cfif>


<select name="rating">
 <option value="">&ndash; Rate This Poem &ndash;</option>
 <option value="1"<cfif duplicateCheck.score eq 1> selected="selected"</cfif>>1</option>
 <option value="2"<cfif duplicateCheck.score eq 2> selected="selected"</cfif>>2</option>
 <option value="3"<cfif duplicateCheck.score eq 3> selected="selected"</cfif>>3</option></select>

Answer (score 0):

If you loop through your list of options you could do this dynamically.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="thisOption">
   <option value="#thisOption#" <cfif userHasSelected eq thisOption> selected="selected"   
   </cfif>>#thisOption#</option>
</cfloop>
```

Or you can move the code to select the drop down out of the option html, which i prefer.

```
<cfloop from="1" to="3" index="thisOption">
   <cfset variables.selected = userHasSelected eq thisOption? 'selected' : '' />
   <option value="#thisOption#" #selected#>#thisOption#</option>
</cfloop>
```